# How to pass arguments to interactive mode?

Tags: node.js

Why doesn't this work? I am trying to invoke the REPL with some arguments.

```
tmp % node -- --name='jon'
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '--name=jon'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `node -`

This means "read input from stdin" and node won't interpret the argument as a file to be read.

When `node -` is run in an interactive terminal, stdin will be a tty (i.e. the terminal input) so node default to the interactive session.

```
$ node - --name=jon   
Welcome to Node.js v18.13.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> process.argv
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '-',
  '--name=jon'
]
```

Without a tty, `node -` expects the script to be the input:

```
$ echo 'console.log(process.argv)' | node - --name=jon
[ '/usr/local/bin/node', '-', '--name=jon' ]
```